# Double limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{y^2 f(x) - x^2 f(y)}{(1-\cos x)\sin (x-y)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $I$ be an open interval containing $0$, and $f: I \rightarrow R$ be differentiable and $f'$ be continuous. Compute:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{y^2 f(x) - x^2 f(y)}{(1-\cos x)\sin (x-y)}$$

This is my work:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0} \lim_{y\rightarrow x} \frac{y^2 x^2 (\frac{f(x)}{x^2}-\frac{f(y)}{y^2})(x-y)}{(1-\cos x)(x-y)\sin(x-y)}$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow0} \frac{x^4}{1 - \cos x} \frac{xf'(x) - 2f(x)}{x^3}$$

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x}{1-\cos x} (xf'(x) - 2f(x)) $$

But it doesn't feel right because I'm "missing" one power of x to have $\frac{x}{1-\cos x}$ converge. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It seems that some condition like $f(0)=0$ is actually missing instead.

Comment: @Saad I forgot to add: derivative of f is continuous.

Comment: Please explain how you evaluate the inner limit. I get the same result but without the term involving $f(x)$.

Comment: The power of $x$ in $\dfrac x{1-\cos x}\sim\dfrac2x$ is indeed correct, but $\lim\limits_{x→0}\dfrac{f(x)}x$ does not necessarily exist.

Comment: @maxmilgram I make a difference quotient by force to make use of assumption that f is differentiable. $\lim_{y \rightarrow x} \frac{h(x) - h(y)}{x-y}$ = $h'(x)$ where $h(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ Also I make use of standard limit $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin z}{z} = 1$. But

Answer (score 1):

Applying l'Hospital's rule to the inner limit gives
$-(2xf(x) - x^2f'(x))/(1 + cos x)$.

Now applying the rule to the outer limit gives
$(2f(x) - x^2f''(x))/sin x$

which diverges for bounded f and f" unless f(0) = 0.

Comment: Does the second derivative need to exist?

Comment: @BagofChips.  I assumed it did to explore the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Split the numerator as $$y^2f(x)-x^2f(x)+x^2f(x)-x^2f(y)$$ and replace the $\sin(x-y) $ with $(x-y) $ to get the limit $y\to x$ as $$\frac{x^2f'(x)-2xf(x)}{1-\cos x} $$ and the desired limit as $x\to 0$ of above fraction exists if and only if limit $L=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)/x$ exists and in that case the desired limit is $2f'(0)-4L$.